# Cannot play Vimeo video inside Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, vimeo

I'm displaying a web page inside an Android's WebView. The page includes an embedded video from Vimeo.

But when I try to display the page inside the WebView, the video area appears blank.
In the log , I see the following logs:

> W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 4 for video/hevc
>
> W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc

The video displays fine when opening the web page using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enabled Javascript for WebView note that can cause XSS vulnerability.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Great answer @n3dx ! Thanks a lot :)